# Subdomain on another host (another IP, another provider)

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, vps, subdomain, host

Let's say my main domain is `domain.net` and i'm using it on a **Media Temple** (gs) server.

I have my blog on the subdomain `blog.domain.net`

Now I want to host my blog on my new VPS from **Linode**.

So, I need to keep `domain.net` on **Media Temple** and `blog.domain.net` on **Linode**.

Is this possible? Any advice?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is possible. All you have to do is create an [**A**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) record in your domain.net DNS for blog.domain.net which points to the IP address of the server at Linode.

Here is a link to the Media Temple [**documentation**](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/60/How+can+I+change+the+DNS+records+for+a+domain+I+registered%7B47%7Dhost+with+%28mt%29+Media+Temple?) for this.